# connecting PLC to my mfc program

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, plc, scada

In current scenario i am using RS-232 communication for operating hardware component from PC using Micro Controller in between.Whole Application is Created in MFC.

I am thinking to connect PLC for communicating hardware component to PC. So can anyone tell me how we can done this?

Comment: PLC having RS-232 as hardware interface.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what hardware interface the PLC provides. If it does not use RS-232 (or ethernet) then you need an adapter. If your PC accepts plugin cards then you can probably get an adapter and driver in that form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out what *protocol* is used to communicate with the PLC e.g. COMLI, knowing that you will give you an abstract model to work with that you can use to control the hardware.